# Add last_access_date field to the shallow_user object

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, api-v2, users

Would it be possible to add the `last_access_date` field to the `shallow_user` object? I presume this corresponds to the `seen` field when visiting someone's profile.

My reasoning is that it saves the extra API call to the *full* user object *just* to retrieve this one field. This of course is in the context of doing `/search` (or similar) queries.

Comment: This is the problem with shallow_user there will always be a field wanted from `user`. This is exactly the problem filters solve. Please Kevin can we get rid of the shallow_user?

Comment: @Jonathan. There's a good chance I've missed the point so bare with me :) Ignore the `shallow_user` object for now. How would I retrieve the _full_ user object in a `/search` query using _filters_?

Comment: With filters you could choose which field you want and don't want from the full user object. So if the /search query return user objects. Eg, You can choose that you want the `accept_rate` and `last_access_date` fields but not the `reputation` field. So rather than asking for fields to copied from the user object to shallow_user you can just untick the fields you don't want. The same also goes for network_user.

Comment: @Jonathan. Right, you meant _if_ a `/search` query returned the full user object - yeah I missed that part. I don't think what you're asking for will be feasible. To be honest, I don't see them even adding the field I wanted. I don't know how their stuff is structured in the backend, but I can imagine that it will be _very_ expensive to return a _full_ user object with each (relevant) query.

Comment: @Jonathan. From what I understand of filters (in this context), you enable or disable only what you need, but on the backend, _all_ those objects are pulled no matter what - filters only prevent them from being sent to you (thus conserving bandwidth). That's probably the reason they went with the `shallow_user` object in the first place. Then again, this could all be heresay :)

Comment: I was going to something I thought I heard, that the filters were more integrated, and only the fields checked are pulled (I think it was something about the total field being expensive on their side and thats why it is disabled in default filter, and been replaced with has_more), but I don't know if thats true, so my comments are made on the assumption that it's true, if it's not then I completely understand the point of shallow_user and my comments are invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [shallow_user](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/shallow-user) type contains only fields that are "fast" to fetch, as it's always returned as a member of other (potentially expensive to fetch) types.

Accordingly, we can't add any fields to `shallow_user` that aren't "fast" and in generally, won't add things that aren't really commonly needed.  I don't think the `last_access_date` is required often enough to take the perf hit.

---

As to the reason for separate user and shallow_user types, if we didn't have them it'd be far too easy to craft queries that include too much of users to be reasonable to execute (trivial example, `/search` with a tag and all user fields would hit something like 5 tables in the cache-miss case on top of actually running the search).

We could use filters I suppose, but we'd be in an awkward situation where certain combinations of fields would have to be forbidden.  Simpler to just have a different type, at least in my opinion.